# Javascript Use a returned value for a boolean comparison

Tags: javascript

If I have:

```
function Function1(){
    var Value = true;

    return Value;

};
```

How can I use the returned value "Value" in another function for it to be used as true, if I use it as below, it doesn't returns nothing.

```
function Function2(){
    if(Function1 == true){
        console.log("Hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `if(Function1())`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xufox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Function2(){
    if(Function1() == true){
        console.log("Hello")
    }
}
```

only replace `Function2` with `Function2()`

Comment: The `== true` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the returned value you need to call the function first. What you're doing is evaluating the function itself, not the returned value.

You also don't need the `== true` part because it will evaluate the returned value anyway.

Change your code to:

```
function Function2(){
    if(Function1()){
        console.log("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Function2` needs to be like this:

```
function Function2(){
    if(Function1()){
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

It is because you are calling a function and not a variable.
So since you are calling `Function1` you need to make sure that you are calling it like this `Function1()`.

If you are calling a variable you can just use the name.

And also since it is a variable of type `boolean` you can simply use `if(Function1())` and omit the `== true`.

And you call it like this:

```
var k = Function1();
```

Comment: `Function2()` doesn't return a value and so the value of `k` will be `undefined`. I think you meant calling `Function1` there ;).

Comment: @Botimoo Yeah, you are right. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have to type brackets '()' after the function:

```
function Function2(){
    if(Function1() == true){
        console.log("Hello")
    }
}
```

Because now Syntax Parser thinks that Function1 is a variable.

Comment: `Function1` _is_ a variable. This is unrelated to the issue. The problem is that `Function1` doesn’t call the function; `Function1()` does. There’s no “maybe” in that.

Comment: Yes, you right.